# Transit between Tokyo airports with Singapore Airlines

Tags: transit, public-transport, nrt, singapore-airlines, hnd

I am flying from Los Angeles International Airport (LAX) to India NSCBI (CCU) Airport. My flight has two layovers - Tokyo and then Singapore. The different legs of the journey are **on the same itinerary**. I am **flying with Singapore Airlines**. I **land in Tokyo Haneda Airport** at 8 pm and my **connecting flight is from Narita International Airport** the next day 2:30 am. My question is whether Singapore Airlines would be responsible for my transit as I don't have a lot of time (six and a half hours not considering checking in, etc.) or do I have to arrange my own transportation?

Comment: Ask Singapore Airlines. They should provide you the best information (and up to date). Ask also about your baggage. You may find some information online, but there is no better way than to make initial contact.

Comment: The LAX-HND segment must be operated by some other airline, since Singapore Airlines doesn't fly that route.  Possibly ANA?

Comment: LAX to HND segment is also a singapore airlines flight atleast in my itinerary @Nate.

Comment: @Giacomo thanks ... I was planning to do that as that makes most sense at present!

Comment: I think you're actually flying LAX-NRT followed by HND-SIN like [this](https://i.imgur.com/BIUybcE.png), as Singapore Airlines doesn't fly LAX-HND. Since, as Hilmar explained, you're most likely responsible for your bags (and definitely for getting a Japanese visa), maybe consider changing your routing to something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/YD4Sqz4.png) or, even better, [this one](https://i.imgur.com/Wu3nzDL.png)? All of these itineraries seem to be similarly priced, so you'd only have to pay a change fee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After flying this itinerary, I can narrate my experience for any future travellers along this route. The answer given by @hilmar is more or less accurate. Please note that if you happen to **choose this itinerary with Singapore Airlines,  then you need to arrange for your own transport between airports along with your check-in luggage**. I am talking specifically about layovers in Japan and so this same situation in a different city may end up with a different outcome.

Once I landed at Haneda, I went through customs and before exiting the airport went to the limousine-bus counter. I had not pre-booked to account for flight delays. I was told that **all outbound limousine-buses for that day were booked to capacity**. Next-best option was the train. The link given in @hilmar's answer is pretty accurate when it comes to the fares. Both airports have underground metro stations connecting them which you can access without actually stepping out of the airport. Nevertheless, the Japanese metro map is a literal labyrinth and the only hope for foreigner tourists like us is to ask the information centres for guidance. The people at the desk are quite friendly and helpful and will help you with paper maps and writing directions on pieces of paper as to at which station you need to switch trains. One disadvantage I faced was that I found out (nasty surprise) that your only hope there to purchase a train ticket is either with JPY or $ or other *banknotes* (like INR, RMB etc) which after exchange for JPY can get you your ticket. **No cards are accepted.** If you have other currency apart from JPY that will be accepted at exchange kiosks for JPY at a competitive rate. I exchanged $20 for 2011 JPY when the market rate was 108.89 JPY per $1. Train ticket cost me 1680 JPY which came cheaper than the limousine bus ticket priced at roughly 3400 JPY. Transit time was around 95 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

This is bad itinerary. Unless there is a specific arrangement with your ticket (ask the airline), you have to arrange your own connection.

Typically you need to

1. Collect your bags
2. Clear Japanese Immigration and Customs, make sure you have proper entry documentation (Visa)
3. Find ground transport to Narita. A list of option is here https://pretraveller.com/narita-airport-nrt-to-haneda-airport-hnd-transfer/ Easiest is the limobus but I don't think it runs that late
4. Go to the check in counter of the airline for you departing flight in Narita
5. Check in and drop off bags again
6. Go through security and immigration (I think)
7. Go to gate.

While it's a significant hassle, 6.5 hours is plenty of time to make it unless there are unforeseen problems.

Things are a lot easier, if you don't check bags and hust use carry on.